# Shell script to validate hex value

Tags: regex, bash, shell

How to validate whether the given input string is valid Hex value or not using regex in shell scripts

For example:

```
Input var="ff:ff:fe:ff"
```

There is a `:` deliminator value

I want to use this regex for any input String

```
var = "ff:ff:fe:ff:fe"
var = "ff:ff:fe:ff:fe:fe:ff:ff"
\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b



#!/bin/bash -x
var="fe:fe:fe:fe"
regex="/^([0-9A-F]+:?){4}$/"
if [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; then
echo "valid"
fi
```

Comment: −1. What have you tried? Which *shell* scripting language is this (it is _not_ bash)?

Comment: \b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b what i tried

Comment: Your question remains unclear. Read the FAQ on how to improve it.

Comment: I understand it. It looks like @Tom Regner did, too. This question and Subsequent answer helped me a lot - THANKS! PointedEars' comment seems pointless now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better version (thanks to chepner):

```
^([[:xdigit:]]{2})(:[[:xdigit:]]{2})*$
```

Test

```
if [[ "ff:af:ff:23:a2:ad" =~ ^([[:xdigit:]]{2})(:[[:xdigit:]]{2})*$ ]]; then
   echo "match";
fi
```

Old Answer:

```
^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$
```

Test

```
$ if [[ "ff:af:ff:23:a2:ad" =~ ^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$ ]]; then 
   echo "match"; 
  fi 
$ match

$ if [[ "definitlynottherightformat" =~ ^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})*$ ]]; then 
   echo "match"; 
  fi 
$
```

Comment: You can use `[[:xdigit:]]` in place of `[[0-9A-F-a-f]]`.